# Raster Marginals Shuffling in Julia - Better implementation

Tags: algorithm, julia, shuffle

I would like to implement a shuffling method for a matrix of zeros and ones that takes random 2x2 submatrices and flips them only if they their colsums and rowsums are equal i.e. [0 1; 1 0] or [1 0; 0 1].

EDIT: FYI this should mean that both

```
sum(matrix,1) == sum(shuffledmatrix,1) && 
sum(matrix,2) == sum(shuffledmatrix,2)
```

==> true

The code below is correct but basically is just not fast enough. Can anyone see any glaring errors here? (I'm fairly new to Julia!)

```
function rastershuffle!(shuffledmatrix::Array{Int32,2},minchanges::Int)
    @inbounds begin
        numchanges = 0
        numcols = size(shuffledmatrix,2)
        numrows = size(shuffledmatrix,1)
        while numchanges < minchanges
            a = findmargeflip!(shuffledmatrix,numcols::Int, numrows::Int)
            numchanges = numchanges + sum(a) 
        end
    end
    return shuffledmatrix
end

function findmargeflip!(shuffledmatrix::Array{Int32,2},numcols::Int, numrows::Int)
    change = false
    cols = EPhys.random_generator(2,numcols)
    rows = EPhys.random_generator(2,numrows)
    vall = sub(shuffledmatrix, [rows[1]; rows[2]],[cols[1]; cols[2]])
    if vall == [0 1; 1 0] || vall == [1 0; 0 1]
        flipvall!(vall)
        #numchanges += 1
        change = true
    end
    change
end

function flipvall!(vall)
    if vall[1] == 1
        vall[:] = [0 1 1 0]    
    else
        vall[:] = [1 0 0 1]
    end
    nothing
end
```

What I've tried so far based on the info in the docs:

- Using BitArrays instead of Int32 - didn't make much difference although I may change this anyway, the function flipvall! can also then just be replaced with flipbits!
- Giving the compiler extra type information
- Setting a number of iterations as opposed to changes and then trying to vectorise using @simd

I think the main bottle neck is re-generating the SubArray each iteration which requires memory re-allocation / garbage collection but I'm not entirely sure how to get round this.

Extra Info:

```
shuffledspikematrix3 = copy(spikematrixnonoise)
@time rastershuffle!(shuffledspikematrix3, 100);
@profile rastershuffle!(shuffledspikematrix3, 100);
Profile.print()
```

===> OUTPUT:

```
 8.776213 seconds (153.35 M allocations: 7.835 GB, 15.94% gc time)
    1   abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1060
    1   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 974
    2   abstractarray.jl; vcat; line: 733
    2   array.jl; getindex; line: 282
    2   multidimensional.jl; start; line: 99
    800 task.jl; anonymous; line: 447
     800 .../IJulia/src/IJulia.jl; eventloop; line: 143
      800 ...rc/execute_request.jl; execute_request_0x535c5df2; line: 183
       800 loading.jl; include_string; line: 266
        800 profile.jl; anonymous; line: 16
         800 In[174]; rastershuffle!; line: 7
          1   ...devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 52
          1   In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 15
          77  In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 16
           13 ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 44
            7 random.jl; rand; line: 255
             5 random.jl; gen_rand; line: 88
              1 dSFMT.jl; dsfmt_fill_array_close1_open2!; line: 66
              4 dSFMT.jl; dsfmt_fill_array_close1_open2!; line: 67
            2 random.jl; rand; line: 256
           47 ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 47
           1  ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 48
           13 ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 49
           1  ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 52
          86  In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 17
           9  ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 44
            5 random.jl; rand; line: 255
             4 random.jl; gen_rand; line: 88
              4 dSFMT.jl; dsfmt_fill_array_close1_open2!; line: 67
            1 random.jl; rand; line: 256
           53 ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 47
           1  ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 48
           13 ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 49
           2  ....devel/src/helper.jl; random_generator; line: 52
          211 In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 19
           87 abstractarray.jl; vcat; line: 733
           9  subarray.jl; _sub; line: 90
           35 subarray.jl; _sub; line: 91
            1  subarray.jl; _sub_unsafe; line: 96
            21 subarray.jl; _sub_unsafe; line: 125
            1  subarray.jl; _sub_unsafe; line: 437
            1  subarray.jl; _sub_unsafe; line: 440
          411 In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 20
           5   abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1060
           4   abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1066
           258 abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1067
           4   abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1068
           2   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 957
           87  abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 960
           1   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 961
           2   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 969
           3   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 970
           11  abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 971
           1   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 974
          4   In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 25
          1   abstractarray.jl; ==; line: 1060
          2   abstractarray.jl; hvcat; line: 960
          1   abstractarray.jl; vcat; line: 733
    1   tuple.jl; ==; line: 95
    3   tuple.jl; ==; line: 96
```

Comment: The first assignment to `vall` in `findmargeflip!` is unnecessary, and potentially confuses the compiler.

Comment: Yeah not sure why that line was there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative implementation of the same function (if I understand what it does correctly). There is a good chance it will work faster, but it doesn't use the same random source as the OP. Looking at it, might give suggestions for optimization.

Hope this helps.

```
function flipit!(m, flipcount)
  zeroinds = map(x->ind2sub(m,x),find(m .== 0))  # find 0 locations
  zerorows = Set{Int}(map(first,zeroinds))       # find rows with 0s
  zerocols = Set{Int}(map(last,zeroinds))        # find cols with 0s
  oneinds = map(x->ind2sub(m,x),find(m .== 1))   # find 1 locations
  filter!(x->x[1] in zerorows && x[2] in zerocols,oneinds) # must satisfy trivially
  n = length(oneinds)
  numflips = 0
  badcount = 0                                   
  badcorners = Set{Tuple{Int,Int}}()       # track bad rectangles
  maxbad = binomial(length(oneinds),2)  # num candidate rectangles
  maxbad == 0 && error("Can't find candidate rectangle")
  randbuf = rand(1:n,2*flipcount)       # make some rands to use later
  while numflips < flipcount
    if length(randbuf)==0
      randbuf = rand(1:n,2*flipcount)  # refresh rands
    end
    cornersinds = minmax(pop!(randbuf),pop!(randbuf))
    if first(cornersinds)==last(cornersinds) continue ; end
    if cornersinds in badcorners                             
      continue                                    # bad candidate
    end
    corners = (oneinds[cornersinds[1]],oneinds[cornersinds[2]])
    if m[corners[1][1],corners[2][2]] == 0 &&     # check 0s
      m[corners[2][1],corners[1][2]] == 0        
      m[corners[1]...] = 0                        # flip
      m[corners[2]...] = 0
      m[corners[1][1],corners[2][2]] = 1
      m[corners[2][1],corners[1][2]] = 1
      oneinds[cornersinds[1]] = (corners[1][1],corners[2][2]) # flip corner list
      oneinds[cornersinds[2]] = (corners[2][1],corners[1][2])
      numflips += 1
      if badcount>0
        badcount = 0
        empty!(badcorners)
      end
    else
      push!(badcorners,cornersinds)     # remember bad candidate
      badcount += 1
      if badcount == maxbad             # if candidates exhausted
        error("No flippable rectangle")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Use with `flipit!(M,n)` where `M` is the matrix and `n` is the number of flips desired. This is not the cleanest code, in an attempt to prefer clarity to compactness.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to start working on this again tomorrow/Sunday so I'll give this a whirl then!

Comment: There are some good ideas but my understanding of this is that because it calcutates the positions of 1s and 0s the conditional "if m[corners[1][1],corners[2][2]] == 0" will be applied to the original matrix and so may not hold true from the 2nd iteration onwards... This is the bit that I'm struggling to get round as it seems to be difficult to deal with this without allocating lots of memory at each step.

Comment: The issue with having the conditions checked correctly after the first iteration is taken care of by the `oneinds` updates commented by `# flip corner list`. Essentially, it keeps the positions of the 1s in the matrix (stored in `oneinds`) correct after the flip. All the flips and the checks are done on the same matrix `m`, so the 0 checks will be done on the matrix after the flips.
The best way is perhaps to test the routine with low flip counts on a sample matrix to see it works correctly. And, of course, to benchmark this routine (and other working implementations) to see which is fastest.

Comment: But there might be an issue with the `badcorners` set. It was meant mainly as an optimization and to check for a non-flipable matrix. Let me see if this is a significant bug.

Comment: ... Yes, it is significant. I'm resetting the `badcorners` set as a fix. It shouldn't have a big performance penalty. Why? Because in the case there are few good rectangles, there won't be a lot of resets, and when there are many, the `badcorners` optimization has little effect.

Comment: To bring the point home, try running the function on the matrix: `testm = [i<j ? 1 : 0 for i=1:10,j=1:10]`. The version in the OP will not terminate.

Comment: Another corner case (sort of literally) is `cornerm = [i+j<8 && rand(Bool) ? 0 : 1 for i=1:30,j=1:30]`, which should terminate (with high probability), but the running time in the OP is much slower.

Comment: Thanks again ... Done some more profiling and this scales really well when lots of flips have to be done but not when the matrix is very large whereas my OP does the opposite. Thinking of ways to reduce the initial overhead for flipit! (basically the first four lines are where the code spends >95% of its time) but looks like a better approach overall so thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The profiling clearly told you that the most time is spent on

```
211 In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 19
411 In[174]; findmargeflip!; line: 20
```

which are

```
  vall = sub(shuffledmatrix, [rows[1]; rows[2]],[cols[1]; cols[2]])
  if vall == [0 1; 1 0] || vall == [1 0; 0 1]
```

You are allocating new arrays all over the places.

try replacing `vall == [0 1; 1 0]` with something like

```
 size(val1) == (2,2) && val1[1,1] == 0 &&
     val1[1,2] == 1 && val1[2,1] == 1 && val1[2,2] == 0
```

By the way why do you have mixed `Int32` & `Int64`? To save memory on the matrix?

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I am allocating too much, and why that is a bad idea but struggling to work out how to not make so many new arrays.

Int32/Int64 are an artifact of the data being saved on a different server, I am actually using a BitArray now but that doesn't change the implementation much. Much more concerned about performance/IO than memory at the moment.